# Change the display of an Excel spreadsheet with merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

This my situation:
[image]

The are script or command to make the cells (those combined) graphically equal to those looking in the image, not disunite the cells?

Comment: What do you mean? The "combined cells" is just one big cell.

Comment: You can draw lines with a drawing tool. 0_o

Comment: Give me -3 for questions and someone comments with the crap?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub ChangeDisplay
    Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 250
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 90
end sub
```

Or what exactly?

Comment: No,I would like that the first table with title "Riepilogo attività svolte" is equal to the second table graphically without disunite the cells